# add some temporary code to end of css file with javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add some temporary css code to end of external CSS file or modify it with javacript or jQuery, suppose I have:

```
//mystyle.css
p{color:red}
```

When a user interacts and changes the color via javascript to green I want the mystyle.css file to change as well or create temp.css file dynamically.

Result:

```
//temp.css or newstyle.css
//(not saved/stored on host - just a temporary file in the users browser)
p{color:"red"} 
p{color:"green"} //this code should add by javascript in mystyle.css and remove red or not Never mind bcs browser auto use green insted of red
```

**Note 1**: I dont want to change orginal file with server-side process - I want to remove the new style after user refreshes the page and I dont want use inline styling because I need to copy the new style-code for personal use.

**Note 2**: i dont want overwrite code by set new style i Want Edit before code(Red changed to Green in **Css file** or Add new css code below them in **mystyle.CSS**)

Comment: This is possible, but you're not going about it in the right way. You'd be best to apply the `color: green` to the element in a separate class, and then add that class using JS

Comment: i just need add new style in files to access it.I use window.getcomputedstyle() but it return extra data and default value

Comment: While that's technically possible (with some server side logic), it's literally the worst way to amend CSS styling. Can you please give a much clearer description of exactly what behaviour you're trying to create as I can 100% guarantee you that there is a better way to do it

Comment: My project makes user create a layout real time by jqueryui design it add some only p div span and set their style width display and..Then they get all css styled of their code..i dont use my server for this i want do all in user browser even offilne mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery/JavaScript or other client-side languages, for security reasons, doesn't have access to writing files ( think what might happen if a user run commands via the console... ).
You can write files using server-side languages only.

But, you can ovveride css rules in jQuery.

```
$("p").css('color','green');
```

PS: In your example there is an error. You have to use the ':' instead of '='.

Comment: by this it add inline style in html file i want store in external place to access it easy and copy them

Comment: As he said, it can't be written to a file. If you want to store the values, you can use a database and send the values from the JavaScript to server side code which updates the database.